# How to only bind gridview after a button click?

Tags: .net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a grid view, that is using ObjectDataSource is it's source.

is it possible to only bind the gridview, after i click a button, and have it initially be blank...but keep using ObjectDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Register an `Click` event on the button and handle the binding of the `GridView` in the handler for the button click.

If you want the `GridView` "blank" initially, bind it to an empty IEnumerable of the type you're binding to. It wont contain any rows, but the header will be there.